# Sign Users Out of ASP.NET Application When They Logout From Okta Dashboard

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, okta

We have an ASP.NET MVC application that uses Okta for user authentication.

When an unauthenticated user browses to our app, they are redirected to Okta to log in and are then redirected back to the application, authenticated. When they click "Logout" within the application, they are signed out of the application and signed out of Okta.

The issue is when we click "Logout" from the Okta dashboard. When a user clicks "Logout" from the Okta dashboard, they are signed out of Okta but not signed out of our application. When the user logs in with different credentials in Okta and opens the application, `HttpContext.User.Identity` still contains the previous user information.

Is it possible to set things up such that when a user clicks "Logout" within the Okta dashboard they are *also* logged out of the ASP.NET application? What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior, let me explain.

Let's assume a user is not logged into Okta OR your application. When a user visits your application and clicks "Log In", they are then redirected to Okta to authenticate. When they authenticate to Okta, a new session cookie is created so the user's identity is remembered on the Okta domain (for example, `blah.okta.com`).

Then the user is redirected BACK to your application (`yourwebsite.com`) where they will have an access token and a NEW session cookie (on the `yourwebsite.com` domain) which will keep them logged in there.

So at this point, there are two separate sessions that are active:

- One on your domain (`yourwebsite.com`)
- One on Okta's domain (`blah.okta.com`)

When a user logs out of Okta's dashboard, this means that their token is revoked and the session cookie is deleted (from the Okta `blah.okta.com` domain). BUT, there is no way for Okta to delete the session cookie from YOUR website (`yourwebsite.com`).

Therefore, when your user does something on your website (`yourwebsite.com`), the user's browser will STILL send the session cookie to your backend that contains an Okta access token.

And... Depending on how your web application is configured, it will do one of two things to verify that token:

- It can either validate the token locally using a JSON web token library (which is the default behavior), in which case the token is still valid, so the user is considered "authenticated" and will continue to be able doing things even though their token has been revoked.
- It can validate the token against Okta's authorization server (this is called token introspection), which is a bit slower as it requires an HTTP request to Okta. If this is done, then the user will indeed be recognized as logged out and their session will be destroyed.

So basically, to get the behavior you're talking about, you need to modify the way your web application is validating the user's tokens. You need to switch from using LOCAL VALIDATION to TOKEN INTROSPECTION.

Unfortunately, we don't *yet* have the option to use token introspection in our ASP.NET library. The author of the library has just added that to her backlog =)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @rdegges, happy to see that this made it into the backlog as it can be very useful in this library! In our use case, the client controls the Okta configuration outside of our domain, with this considered would it still be possible to use token introspection (i.e does it require an API token)? And do you have any resources you can point me to showing how to implement token introspection?

Comment: Hey! Here are the API docs for token introspection: https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/oidc/#introspect The only "credentials" you will need to query the endpoint are your client credentials (aka: client ID + secret), so you should be good!